# Collapsing TD width HTML

Tags: html, css

I have HTML such as:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
        <img style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"></img>
        <img style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"></img>
                </td>
                <td>
                    hello world
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

When the page/window is decreased in width, the second image is pushed below the first image.

My question is: Why doesn't the TD cell shrink to to 300 width with the images are stacked? It seems to stay unnessarily large - causing an ugly gap to be between the images and the text of the next cell. Is there any way to force the cell to either 600 or 300 in width depending on how much room there is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand the behavior of the table layout in your example, you need to review
the table width algorithms used by CSS to visually lay out the table:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#auto-table-layout

The table width algorithm looks at the content in the cells making up each column and
determines a mininum and maximum value for the column width.  The algorithm then tries
to allocate enough space to each column taking into account any specified column width
values, specified table width and so on.

In this case, the browser tries to allocate 600px (plus a bit for the white space between the two images) and some width for the text in the second column.

If the window is wide enough, all the content fits in a single line in each table cell.

However, as the window width shrinks, the algorithm will shrink each column width (the details here will vary among browsers since the CSS specification does not prescribe a detail algorithm).

The algorithm appears to be shrink each column proportionately.  For the first column, this forces the images to wrap with the gap to the right.  In this case, the algorithm 
does not do a second pass to redistribute the excess space.  The algorithm works pretty
well if you are wrapping words.  However, when the content is a 300px wide image, the
result is big (ugly) gaps.

So, the table is working as it should, but the results are not ideal.

The table width algorithms try to be efficient by minimizing the number of times it
loops through the content to determine widths and heights.  In this case, a more
sophisticated algorithm would be needed to get more pleasant results, but it would also
be a bit subjective.

Note: To fix the layout problem, you would have to build a JavaScript function to do the
math to get the column width to work out. I think this could be quite difficult to make
it foolproof.

Answer (score 0):

You could add `style='white-space: nowrap;'` to the`td` element to prevent the wrapping.

http://jsfiddle.net/mpWn3/

Comment: That stops the images wrapping at all. I woud like the image to still wrap, but the TD to jump from 600 down to 300, instead of slowly shrinking to 300 as the width of the page decreases.

Answer (score 0):

My short answer would be to stop using tables and dive into a responsive div layout.

```
<div class='con'>
    <div class='picture_con'>
        <img src='img1.jpg'></img>
        <img src='img2.jpg'></img>
    </div>
    <div class='text_con'>
        Your text here
    </div>
</div>
```

And then make it work with css

```
.con {
    width:100%;
}
.con .picture_con {
    display:inline-block;
}
.con .picture_con img {
    width:300px;
    display:inline;
}
.con .text_con {
    display:inline;
}
```

This is all very well for big screens but now we need to deal with smaller screens.  To do this we use @media css queries

```
@media(max-width:600px) {
    .con .picture_con {
        width:300px;
    }
    .con .picture_con img {
        display:block;
    }
}
```

**Edit: If tables are really necessary**

Here is an example of a responsive table design that does the job aswell

http://jsfiddle.net/4VHd5/

Comment: @MarcAudet oops, must have copied the wrong link.  Fixed now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take the widths away from your image tag. Add them in css for a start...

table img {max-width:100%;}

but yes - you would be better off with making it responsive. This is possible with tables. Read this article: http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/