# Need Table TD Collapse when a value is selected<td> in AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Need Table TD Collapse when a value is selected.

when i click a 3rd  value of first row i want to append a new row below for its corresponding value using Jquery Ajax.

Here I am using jquery $(document).ready(function(){ is using to get value on loading .

when i clicking 3rd  the  page is refreshing and append value of 2nd row is hided and getting only default page  .

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@page import="bean.TestCaseBean,dao.TestCaseDao,java.util.ArrayList,java.util.Iterator"%>

        <%

    TestCaseDao upd=new TestCaseDao();
// arl=new TestCaseBean();
// ArrayList<TestCaseBean>  arl=upd.modulecount();
/*   ArrayList<TestCaseBean>  arl1=upd.moduleTDopen(); */
%>



            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
            <html>

            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

            </head>


            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>BTG</title>

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <!-- style page -->
            <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">


            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

            <script src="../jQuery/jQuery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
            <script src="../jQuery/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>





            <script>
                /*
                                    Please consider that the JS part isn't production ready at all, I just code it to show the concept of merging filters and titles together !
                                    */
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('.filterable .btn-filter').click(function() {
                        var $panel = $(this).parents('.filterable'),
                            $filters = $panel.find('.filters input'),
                            $tbody = $panel.find('.table tbody');
                        if ($filters.prop('disabled') == true) {
                            $filters.prop('disabled', false);
                            $filters.first().focus();
                        } else {
                            $filters.val('').prop('disabled', true);
                            $tbody.find('.no-result').remove();
                            $tbody.find('tr').show();
                        }
                    });

                    $('.filterable .filters input').keyup(function(e) {
                        /* Ignore tab key */
                        var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
                        if (code == '9') return;
                        /* Useful DOM data and selectors */
                        var $input = $(this),
                            inputContent = $input.val().toLowerCase(),
                            $panel = $input.parents('.filterable'),
                            column = $panel.find('.filters th').index($input.parents('th')),
                            $table = $panel.find('.table'),
                            $rows = $table.find('tbody tr');
                        /* Dirtiest filter function ever ;) */
                        var $filteredRows = $rows.filter(function() {
                            var value = $(this).find('td').eq(column).text().toLowerCase();
                            return value.indexOf(inputContent) === -1;
                        });
                        /* Clean previous no-result if exist */
                        $table.find('tbody .no-result').remove();
                        /* Show all rows, hide filtered ones (never do that outside of a demo ! xD) */
                        $rows.show();
                        $filteredRows.hide();
                        /* Prepend no-result row if all rows are filtered */
                        if ($filteredRows.length === $rows.length) {
                            $table.find('tbody').prepend($('<tr class="no-result text-center"><td colspan="' + $table.find('.filters th').length + '">No result found</td></tr>'));
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#btnhome").click(function() {
                        location.href = "BTMHomePage.jsp";

                    });
                    $("#btnback").click(function() {
                        window.history.back();

                    });
                    $('#example').DataTable({
                        "dom": '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">'
                    });
                });
            </script>

            <style>
                .filterable {
                    margin-top: 15px;
                }

                .filterable .panel-heading .pull-right {
                    margin-top: -20px;
                }

                .filterable .filters input[disabled] {
                    background-color: transparent;
                    border: none;
                    cursor: auto;
                    box-shadow: none;
                    padding: 0;
                    height: auto;
                }

                .body {
                    font-family: arial;
                    font-size: 11px;
                    line-height: 1.42857143;
                    color: #333;
                }

                .filterable .filters input[disabled]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
                    color: #333;
                }

                .filterable .filters input[disabled]::-moz-placeholder {
                    color: #333;
                }

                .filterable .filters input[disabled]:-ms-input-placeholder {
                    color: #333;
                }

                .panel-primary>.panel-heading {
                    color: #fff;
                    background-color: #bbc3cb;
                    border-color: #bbc3cb;
                }

                .panel-title {

                    font-size: 12px;
                }

                .panel-heading {
                    padding: 8px;
                }

                .form-control {
                    font-size: 11px;
                    width: 80%;
                    height: 25px;
                }

                body {
                    font-size: 10px;
                    font-family: calibri;
                }

                .panel-primary {
                    border-color: rgba(18, 18, 19, 0.22);
                }

                .modal-footer {
                    text-align: center;
                    border-top: 0;
                    padding: 25px;
                    padding-right: 208px;
                }
            </style>

            <!--  <script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function(){

    alert("hieeee");

    $("#rowfirst").hide();
    /*  $('#desc01').append('<tr class="filters" id="desc01 tr"><td>' + "MODULE" +'</td> </tr>'); */

    if($("#count1").attr('id')=="count1"){

      alert($("#count1").attr('id'));
      $("#count1").click(function(){
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
        $.ajax({
          url : "moduleTDopen",
          dataType : 'json',
          //contentType : 'application/json',
          type : 'POST',
          async : true,
          success : function(res) { 
            //alert("hiiiijj"+trList);
            var b=JSON.parse(res.coremodule);
            console.log(b); 
            $("#rowfirst").show();
            //$(".cd tr").remove();
            if(b.length=="0") {

              $('#rowfirst').append('<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td> No Data Found </td><td></td><td></td></tr>');
            }
            else{ 
              for ( var i = 0; i < b.length; i++)    { 

                alert("fds"+b[i].application);
                //$('#desc01').append('<tr class="filters cd" ><td ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" onclick="return fnclick('+b[i].Glcode+');"> </span> </td> <td> '+b[i].Glcode+' </td> <td><a href="">'+b[i].Gldesc+'</a></td></tr>');
                /* $('#rowfirst').append('<tr class="filters cd" ><td> '+b[i].count+' </td> </tr>'); */


                $('#rowfirst').append('<tr class="filters cd" ><td></td> <td></td> <td> '+b[i].count+' </td> <td></td>  <td></td>  <td></td>  <td></td>  <td></td>  <td></td> </tr>');

              }
            } 


          }



        });
      });
    }
  });

</script>  -->





            <script type="text/javascript">
                /* function fnclick1(a){
                                        alert(a);

                                        $.ajax({
                                            url : "moduleTDopen",
                                            dataType : 'json',
                                            //contentType : 'application/json',
                                            type : 'POST',
                                            async : true,
                                            success : function(res) {   
                                                //alert("hiiiijj"+trList);
                                                var b=JSON.parse(res.coremodule);
                                                console.log(b); 

                                                    var j=1;
                                                    for ( var i = 0; i < 3; i++)     { 


                                                        $('#data').append('<tr ><td>'+j+'</td><td>'+b[i].application+'</td> <td onclick="fnclick1('+j+');"><a href="">'+b[i].count+' </a></td> <td> '+b[i].count1+' </td> <td>'+b[i].count2+'</td>  <td>'+b[i].count3+'</td>    <td></td>  <td></td>  <td></td> </tr>');
                                                        alert("dsjh");
                                                        if(j==2){
                                                            for ( var i = 0; i < b.length; i++)  { 
                                                            $('#data').append('<tr><td></td> <td></td> <td> '+b[i].module+' </td> <td></td>  <td></td>  <td></td>  <td></td>  <td></td>  <td></td> </tr>');
                                                            }
                                                            }

                                                        j++;

                                                    }



                                                }



                                        });


                                        } */

                $(document).ready(function() {

                    alert("hieeee");
                    alert($("#data > tbody > tr").length);

                    $('#data').append('<tr><td>1</td><td>APPLICATION</td> <td name="rows" id=1 onclick=fn1(26);><a href="">26 </a></td> <td> 156 </td> <td>3679</td>  <td>3680</td>    <td></td>  <td></td>  <td></td> </tr>');

                    $('#data').append('<tr><td>3</td><td>APPLICATION</td> <td name="rows" id=2 ><a href="">32 </a></td> <td> 256 </td> <td>4679</td>  <td>4680</td>    <td></td>  <td></td>  <td></td> </tr>');

                    /* 
                            if($("#data > tbody > tr").length=="0"){
                          $.ajax({
                                url : "modulecount",
                                dataType : 'json',
                                //contentType : 'application/json',
                                type : 'POST',
                                async : true,
                                success : function(res) {   
                                    //alert("hiiiijj"+trList);

                                    alert("ajax success");
                                    var b=JSON.parse(res.modulecount);
                                    console.log(b); 
                                    //$("#rowfirst").show();
                                    var j = 1;
                                    for ( var i = 0; i < b.length; i++)  { 
                                    $('#data').append('<tr  ><td>'+j+'</td><td>'+b[i].application+'</td> <td name="rows" id='+j+' onclick=fn1('+b[i].count+');><a href="">'+b[i].count+' </a></td> <td> '+b[i].count1+' </td> <td>'+b[i].count2+'</td>  <td>'+b[i].count3+'</td>    <td></td>  <td></td>  <td></td> </tr>');
                                j++;
                                    }
                                }

                            });



                          //$("input[name ='rows']").click(function()


                            } */
                    /* $("input[name ='rows']").click(function(){
                                        $('#data').append('<tr><td>3</td><td>APPLICATION2</td> <td name="rows" id=2 onclick=fn1(32);><a href="">32 </a></td> <td> 256 </td> <td>4679</td>  <td>4680</td>    <td></td>  <td></td>  <td></td> </tr>');
                                    }); */



                });
            </script>
            <script>
                function fn1(a) {
                    alert("chk" + a);

                    $('#data').append('<tr><td>2</td><td>chk</td> <td name="rows" id=3 onclick=fn1(3);><a href="">3 </a></td> <td>  </td> <td></td>  <td></td>    <td></td>  <td></td>  <td></td> </tr>');

                    return false;
                }
            </script>

            <body>
                <div class="container">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary filterable">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title" style="color:#1f1f21;"><b>SUMMARY OF TEST CASE</b></h3>
                                <div class="pull-right">
                                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-filter" style="margin-left: -5px;margin-bottom: -17px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter"></span>Filter</button>

                                    <label class=" col-sm-offset-3 control-label" style="color: #337ab7;">Function
                  <select class="form-horizontal" name="function" id="function">
                    <option value="O">SELECT</option>
                      <option value="AL">ALL</option>
                        <option value="AP">APPROVED</option>
                          <option value="DR">DROPPED</option>
                            <option value="DL">DELETED</option> 
                              <option value="DC">DISCARDED</option>
                                <option value="NP">NOT APPLICABLE</option>
                                  </select></label>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <table class="table table-hover" id="desc01">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr class="filters">
                                        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="SRLNO" disabled></th>
                                        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="APPLICATION" disabled></th>
                                        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="MODULE" disabled></th>
                                        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="SUB-MODULE " disabled></th>
                                        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="BUSINESS SCENARIOS" disabled></th>
                                        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="OPERATION" disabled></th>
                                        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="NOS" disabled></th>
                                        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="STATUS" disabled></th>
                                        <th>SELECT</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody id="data">
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" id="btnhome">Home</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" value="back" id="btnback">Back</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Collapsing TD width HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23795979/collapsing-td-width-html)

Comment: Hi I Need in Ajax.